# Pandas - Overwrite values with different index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Stackoverflow

Following DataFrame has 2017 earnings data, but Q4 data is in cumulative form. It means 2017 Q4 revenue is the sum of 2017 Q3, 2017 Q2, and 2017 Q1. I want to find Q.4 earnings data and overwrite it on the existing DataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017], 
                    'qtr': ['Q1', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q4'],
                   'acc_nm': ['revenue', 'net_inc','revenue', 'net_inc','revenue', 'net_inc', 'revenue', 'net_inc'],
                   'acc_value' : [10, 5, 11, 6, 12,7, 45, 26]})


    year    qtr acc_nm  acc_value
0   2017    Q1  revenue 10
1   2017    Q1  net_inc 5
2   2017    Q2  revenue 11
3   2017    Q2  net_inc 6
4   2017    Q3  revenue 12
5   2017    Q3  net_inc 7
6   2017    Q4  revenue 33
7   2017    Q4  net_inc 18
```

Here I found the Q4 earnings.

```
df_Total = df[df['qtr'] == 'Q4']['acc_value'].reset_index(drop=True)
df_Q3 = df[df['qtr'] == 'Q3']['acc_value'].reset_index(drop=True)
df_Q2 = df[df['qtr'] == 'Q2']['acc_value'].reset_index(drop=True)
df_Q1 = df[df['qtr'] == 'Q1']['acc_value'].reset_index(drop=True)
df_Q4 = df_Total - (df_Q3 + df_Q2 + df_Q1)
df_Q4

0    12
1     8
Name: acc_value, dtype: int64
```

df_Q4 dataFrame has index from 0 to 1 while df has index from 0 to 7. I don't know how to combine these. Help me community. The desired output is the following.

```
    year    qtr acc_nm  acc_value
0   2017    Q1  revenue 10
1   2017    Q1  net_inc 5
2   2017    Q2  revenue 11
3   2017    Q2  net_inc 6
4   2017    Q3  revenue 12
5   2017    Q3  net_inc 7
**6 2017    Q4  revenue 12**
**7 2017    Q4  net_inc 8**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```python
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017], 
                    'qtr': ['Q1', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q4'],
                   'acc_nm': ['revenue', 'net_inc','revenue', 'net_inc','revenue', 'net_inc', 'revenue', 'net_inc'],
                   'acc_value' : [10, 5, 11, 6, 12,7, 45, 26]})
```

df:

```
   year qtr   acc_nm  acc_value
0  2017  Q1  revenue         10
1  2017  Q1  net_inc          5
2  2017  Q2  revenue         11
3  2017  Q2  net_inc          6
4  2017  Q3  revenue         12
5  2017  Q3  net_inc          7
6  2017  Q4  revenue         45
7  2017  Q4  net_inc         26
```

```
Q4 = df[  (df.qtr == "Q4") & (df.year == 2017) ]
df = df[~((df.qtr == "Q4") & (df.year == 2017))]

Q4['acc_value'] = (Q4.groupby('acc_nm').acc_value.sum() - df.groupby('acc_nm').acc_value.sum()).sort_index(ascending=False).values
df = pd.concat([df, Q4])
```

df:

```
   year qtr   acc_nm  acc_value
0  2017  Q1  revenue         10
1  2017  Q1  net_inc          5
2  2017  Q2  revenue         11
3  2017  Q2  net_inc          6
4  2017  Q3  revenue         12
5  2017  Q3  net_inc          7
6  2017  Q4  revenue         12
7  2017  Q4  net_inc          8
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was hard coding to solve this one by one. I got 500+ companies to do so.  I was never able to think of groupby and tilde sign. THANK YOU